# InnoDB e MyISAM gerando Table already exists error

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, innodb

Estou reformulando algumas telas de meu sistema que, inteiramente, utiliza o MyISAM como Engine do MySQL. No caso, estas telas utilizarão InnoDB pós reformulação.

Exclui, pelo PHPMyAdmin, todas as tabelas MyISAM em questão e até então perfeito, não houve problemas. Entretanto, ao tentar criar as novas tabelas InnoDB (com o mesmo nome) aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Table already exists

O que fazer?

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Adicione um pouco mais de informação visual, mostre a tabela não existindo, o erro do phpMyAdmin, alguma coisa para que possamos tentar achar a origem do erro.

Comment: Adicionei, Filipe! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Descubra a pasta em que estão os arquivos da database e remova eles:

```
Select @@datadir
```

Acesse a pasta retornada pelo select entre na database correspondente e apague os arquivos .MYD, .FRM e MYI. Lembre que é preciso desligar o serviço do mysql para essa tarefa. Por último execute um `SHOW TABLES` e tente criar novamente as tabelas.

Baseado em : [location of database tables mysql windows xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843381/location-of-database-tables-mysql-windows-xp)

relacionado : [schrodinger mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538908/schrodingers-mysql-table-exists-yet-it-does-not)

Comment: Obrigado, perdeu! Tentei o que disse, mas ainda não deu certo! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Segue a solução para quem possa ter o mesmo problema. Caso outra pessoa tenha uma solução mais prática, por favor, não deixem de postar (havia testado diversas soluções pela Internet que não deram certo).

```
Criar no BD original, as tabelas que ainda não existem mas com a engine como MyISAM.
Criar um novo BD com todas as tabelas desejadas com engine InnoDB.
Desligar MySQL.
Remover os arquivos das tabelas do BD original.
Copiar os arquivos das tabelas do novo BD para o BD original.
Definir mysql.mysql como proprietário dos arquivos das tabelas copiadas no BD original.
Conceder permissão 755 para os mesmos arquivos.
Iniciar o MySQL.
```

Li algo a respeito de ser um erro de dicionário. :-)